# Action method parameter set to value of submit button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

This is some legacy ASP.NET MVC3 code I've been asked to look at. It has an action method with two string parameters in addition to the model.

```
public ActionResult RequestUsername(StaffModel model, string request = null, string clear = null)
```

The form that calls this has two submit buttons:

```
<input type="submit" class="button" title="Request username" value="Request Username" name="request" />
<input type="submit" class="button" title="Clear form" value="Clear" name="clear" />
```

If I click the first one, the method parameter called 'request' is set (to "request"). If I click the second button, the method parameter called 'clear' is set (to "clear"). I can't see any custom code that would do this, so I think it must be something in the framework.

My question is: what is doing the mapping between the name attribute of the button being clicked, and the action parameter?

Thanks

Comment: the button is an "input" tag, all inputs send information to server. The form will send the content of the name attribute. That's how input[type="submit"] works in asp.net mvc

Comment: If you want to clear a form you can just use `<input type="reset" value="Clear form" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MVC Model binding process does the mapping between the posted form values and the parameters of your action method.

There is a built-in default class called `DefaultModelBinder` which does this in normal cases, but this can be replaced with your custom implementation if you want.The DefaultModelBinder class can map form data to either String,Int,Decimal,Double or DateTime or your custom class objects.

The important thing to remember is **the name of the form field should match with the name of the action method parameter** for the model binder to work. In your case your submit button's name's matches with the action method parameter name's.

Comment: Thanks Shyju. This all came about because I replaced the submit button with a normal button which then calls a JavaScript function to submit the form after doing some other things first. The button's name is also 'request' but that method parameter value isn't being set any more. So, I guess submit and button input types differ somehow when binding. Investigating DefaultModelBinder now... :)